# Parametrization of curve with linearly increasing curvature

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system

I'm looking for a curve that has a steadily increasing curvature, that is for $\gamma: I \subset \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $C>0$ constant.

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1} \frac{d}{dt} || \gamma^{\prime \prime}(t) || = C, \end{equation} with $|| \gamma^{\prime}(t) || = 1 $ and some initial conditions (say $\gamma(0) = (0,0), \gamma^{\prime}(0) = (1,0), \gamma^{\prime \prime} = (0,0)$).

I know that such a problem most likely has not a closed form, but numerically I could try to search for something. This is what I got to:

Lets name $\gamma(t) = (\gamma_x(t), \gamma_y(t)) = (\gamma_x, \gamma_y)$. By integrating the curvature equation up to time $t$ and taking the square of the norm we get $$ (\gamma_x^{\prime\prime})^2 + (\gamma_y^{\prime\prime})^2 = C^2t^2.$$

Consider the equation for the derivative of $\gamma$, by taking the square and differentiating we obtain: 
\begin{align} (\gamma_x^\prime)^2 + (\gamma_y^\prime)^2 = 1 \\
\Rightarrow \gamma_x^\prime \gamma_x^{\prime \prime} + \gamma_y^{\prime} \gamma_y^{\prime \prime} = 0 \\
\Rightarrow \gamma_x^{\prime \prime} = - \frac{\gamma_y^{\prime} \gamma_y^{\prime \prime}}{\gamma_x^\prime} = - \frac{\gamma_y^{\prime} \gamma_y^{\prime \prime}}{\sqrt{1 - (\gamma_y^{\prime})^2}}  \end{align}

So returning to the equation derived from the curvature, we get a nonlinear differential equation for $\gamma_y$:

\begin{align} 
\frac{(\gamma_y^{\prime}\gamma_y^{\prime \prime})^2}{1-(\gamma_y^{\prime})^2} + (\gamma_y^{\prime \prime})^2 = C^2 t^2 \\  \Rightarrow
(\gamma_y^{\prime \prime})^2 = C^2t^2(1 - (\gamma_y^{\prime})^2) \\
\Rightarrow \gamma_y^{\prime \prime} = - Ct \sqrt{1 - (\gamma_y^{\prime})^2
}
\end{align}

Where in the last step I just took one of the solutions. Now I don't know how to proceed as I'm not familiar with solving nonlinear differential equations. How would you suggest to proceed? or is there any alternative way to obtain such a curve?

Comment: Integrating you should get $||\gamma’’||=Ct+D \geq 0$.

Comment: The initial value is zero for the second derivative.

Comment: By separation of variables you get $\gamma_y'(t)=-\sin(C/2 t^2+D)$. The anti-derivative of this involves special functions (at least that's what Mathematica says).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps an [Euler spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral) (also known as a clothoid)?  Quoting the [Wikipedia entry for "Euler spiral"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral): An Euler spiral is a curve whose curvature changes linearly with its curve length.

In particular, in terms of your notation, reframe $\gamma$ as being the angle of turn after traversing length $t$.  Then compare with [this formulation (at the Wikipedia entry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral#Formulation) which uses $\theta$ where you have used $\gamma$ and $s$ where you have used $t$.  What you have called $(\gamma_x, \gamma_y)$ turn out to be obtainable by Fresnel integrals.  Also see [this question and answers from it](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1174762/190548).